# What could cause one model's views to find another controller's helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.11

I have a view site.com/events/past which sorts a list of events according to either date or category (depending on which is specified).  The sorting is done in the events helper.  For some reason, views/events/past.html.erb is finding the methods (by the same name) in /helpers/places_helper.rb instead of /helpers/events_helper.rb.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you declaring a method with the same name in two helpers?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Isn't the places_helper only accessible to the places views?

Edit: apparently not.  Why isn't that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All helpers are included by default on all controllers due to this method call:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
end
```

To change this behavior you will have to remove this call (or change it to **helper :application**) and at each controller add a:

```
helper :places
```

To include specific helpers as needed.